# CoordinatorLayout. Теряется привязка AppBarLayout после сна устройства

Tags: android, coordinator-layout

Есть фрагмент, где тулбар скрывается с прокруткой RecyclerView. Все хорошо работает до момента засыпания устройства. После пробуждения как будто бы тулбар теряет привязку к списку и скроллится отдельно

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none">


        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/un_background">


            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:titleEnabled="false">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                    <Views.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/cam_swiper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/cam_rv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/un_background"
                app:spanCount="3"
                tools:listitem="@layout/camera_item" />
        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

пример кривой работы 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При чем такая ерунда наблюдается в бОльшей степени на самсунгах, на хлаоми один раз из 5